# RuntimeModelerException: A WebService annotation is not present on class: <EndpointInterface>

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, wsdl, webservice-client

I have a WSDL file. Using that, I generated a web service. This web service is converted to jar added into the client project

And I am trying to invoke a web method from main() in client project

```
    Service serv= Service.create(url, qName);
    Calculator c = serv.getPort(Calculator.class);
    int result = c.multiply(2, 3);
```

When I run this application, Run as ->Java application
I get the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModelerException: A WebService annotation is not present on class: com.test.ws.Calculator
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.getPortTypeName(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.getPortTypeName(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Unknown Source)
at com.test.ws.client.TestClient.main(TestClient.java:26)
```

According to what I understand, the annotation is missing in the generated web service in Calculator.java - and that is true as per the below code
Calculator.java

```
 package com.test.ws;

public interface Calculator extends java.rmi.Remote {
    public int multiply(int arg0, int arg1) throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
  }
```

Now, since I generated the web service code from wsdl through eclipse.. How is it possible that the annotation is missing?
If this is the usual case, then should I add something else in my code?

Looking for some help on this.
Thanks in advance!